# MATLAB loop over string

Tags: matlab

How to iterate over string in MATLAB to get characters for some calculations?

I've got a gps data string:

```
str = "GPRMC,194325.802,A,5321.6802,N,00630.3372,W,0.02,31.66,140420";
```

Need to calculate hash of it by xor operation between characters.

Comment: `str=char(str)+0` gives you a 1D vector of ascii value, then you can loop using either vector operations or for loop

Comment: That's works, thanks a lot!